# How to ignore head part of html file with the help of Parse Delegator

Tags: java, html, parsing

here in output it gives all contents of html file, I want to print only body content of html file
need to ignore all head part from xml file.
using parserdelegator

```
  public static List<String> extractText(Reader reader) throws IOException {

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ParserDelegator parserDelegator = new ParserDelegator();
    ParserCallback parserCallback = new ParserCallback() {
        public void handleText(final char[] data, final int pos) {
            list.add(new String(data));

        }

        public void handleStartTag(Tag tag, MutableAttributeSet attribute, int pos) {

        }

        public void handleEndTag(Tag t, final int pos) {

        }

        public void handleSimpleTag(Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, final int pos) {
        }

        public void handleComment(final char[] data, final int pos) {
        }

        public void handleError(final java.lang.String errMsg, final int pos) {
        }
    };
    parserDelegator.parse(reader, parserCallback, true);
    return list;
}   
  public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("test.xhtml");
            List<String> lines = bodyHtml.extractText(reader);
            for (String line : lines) {                 
                if(line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.println(line.trim());
                }   
            }
          }
```

Comment: So what did you try so far? Do you know how `ParserDelegator` works and how it handles tags? Hint: ignore any content after encountering the start tag for head and until the end tag for head - or only consider body content (i.e. after `<body>` and until `</body>`). `ParserCallback` might need to have some state in that case.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I tried but don't know how to start tag with body tag. it will print all text content of html file.

Comment: In that case you should familiarize yourself with how `ParserDelegator` actually works. I'd assume that methods in `ParserCallback` will be called for each element in the file in the order they are listed, so you could use `handleStartTag()` and `handleEndTag()`to set a flag when you encoutner `<body>` and `</body>` and use that flag in `handleText()` to store or ignore the text.